# Order output value using dynamic input JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic input field that will show the inputted text to preview element, but when I input in a random order, the preview text order is also random.

For example I have 3 input field, the order of filling starts from the 1st field, the 3rd field then the 2nd field. But the results in the preview are the 1st, 3rd and then 2nd field.

```
[test 1][test 2][test 3]
test 1 test 3 test 2
```

What I want is even though the order of filling is random but the results in the preview still match the order of the fields.

```
[test 1][test 2][test 3]
test 1 test 2 test 3
```

This is the HTML file

```
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group row description-form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
              <textarea class="form-control description" data-row="1"></textarea>
              <span class="badge badge-primary">90</span>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block mt-2 add-description">Add More Description +</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="description">
          <span class="description-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the JQuery

```
var row = 1;  
$('.add-description').on('click', function() {
    $('<div class="input-group mb-2">' +
      '<textarea class="form-control description" data-row="' + (row + 1) + '"></textarea>' +
      '<span class="badge badge-primary">90</span>' +
      '</div>').insertBefore(this);
    row++;
  })

  $('.description-form-group').on('keyup', 'textarea.description', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
    var length = val.length;
    var count = 90;
    var total_length = count - length;

    $(this).next().text(total_length);
    if (total_length <= 0) {
      $(this).next().removeClass('badge-primary');
      $(this).next().addClass('badge-danger');
    } else {
      $(this).next().addClass('badge-primary');
      $(this).next().removeClass('badge-danger');
    }

    if (val && row > 1) {
      $('.description > .description-' + row).remove();
      $('.description').append('<span class="description-' + row + '">' + val + '</span>');
    } else {
      $('.description-' + row).text(val);
    }
  })
```

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/madiluzi/6zbkp0wv/)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: its not clear what order you want the preview to show - alphabetical? by word length? Please advise

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide examples of what you would enter and what you want the result to be.

Comment: I've edited the question, maybe it helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var rows = [""];

  function showRows(arr) {
    $("div.description").html("");
    $.each(arr, function(key, val) {
      var row = $("<span>", {
        class: "description-" + key
      }).html(val).appendTo($(".description"));
    });
  }

  $('.add-description').on('click', function() {
    var row = $("textarea.description").length;
    var group = $("<div>", {
      class: "input-group mb-2"
    }).insertBefore(this);
    $("<textarea>", {
      class: "form-control description",
      "data-row": row
    }).appendTo(group);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "badge badge-primary"
    }).html("90").appendTo(group);
  });

  $('.description-form-group').on('keyup', 'textarea.description', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var row = $(this).data("row");
    var length = val.length;
    var total_length = 90 - length;

    $(this).next().text(total_length);
    if (total_length <= 0) {
      $(this).next().removeClass('badge-primary');
      $(this).next().addClass('badge-danger');
    } else {
      $(this).next().addClass('badge-primary');
      $(this).next().removeClass('badge-danger');
    }

    rows[row] = val;
    showRows(rows);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group row description-form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <textarea class="form-control description" data-row="0"></textarea>
          <span class="badge badge-primary">90</span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block mt-2 add-description">Add More Description +</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="description"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This uses an Array to store the values of each Textarea. When changes are made it is updating the proper portion of the Array and redrawing all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain the result in dictionary(object), it will help you to do whatever you want with data.

I have modified some of the code to add data in object.

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group row description-form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                  <textarea class="form-control description" data-row="1"></textarea>
                  <span class="badge badge-primary">90</span>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block mt-2 add-description">Add More Description +</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            <div class="result">
           
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
  var row = 1;
  var data = {"1": ""}; // it will keep entered data with keys as indexes
  $('.add-description').on('click', function() {
    $('<div class="input-group mb-2">' +
      '<textarea class="form-control description" data-row="' + (row + 1) + '"></textarea>' +
      '<span class="badge badge-primary">90</span>' +
      '</div>').insertBefore(this);
    row++;
    data[row] = ""; // enter new key in dictionary with value as empty string
  })

  $('.description-form-group').on('keyup', 'textarea.description', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
    var length = val.length;
    var count = 90;
    var total_length = count - length;
    data[row] = val; // update the value at index(whatever the textarea is)

    $(this).next().text(total_length);
    if (total_length <= 0) {
      $(this).next().removeClass('badge-primary');
      $(this).next().addClass('badge-danger');
    } else {
      $(this).next().addClass('badge-primary');
      $(this).next().removeClass('badge-danger');
    }
        showResult(data);
  })

  // display result
  function showResult(data) {
    let str = '';
    for(let key in data) {
        str += data[key];
    }
    $('.result').text(str);
  }
```

Dictionary will maintain the data with indexes as key

```
{
"1", "test1",
"2", "",
"3", "dfdf",
}
```

so in future if you need to add ability to delete the textarea you can remove data at that index.
It can also be achieved by array.